# How to install Microsoft true type font on Alpine Linux?

Tags: alpine-linux, ttf

I would like to create a Docker image using Alpine Linux and LibreOffice to render PDF documents. The LibreOffice source documents are using Microsofts Times New Roman font.

How can I install Microsoft fonts using `apk` on Alpine Linux? Is there an equivalent packet to Ubuntus `apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`?

**Update 1:**

Meanwhile I have found a package called `[msttcorefonts-installer][1]` that seems to provide what I am looking for. When I try to install it on Alpine Linux 3.7 using `apk add msttcorefonts-installer-3.6-r2` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  msttcorefonts-installer-3.6-r2 (missing):
    required by: world[msttcorefonts-installer-3.6-r2]
```

Comment: Did you check the [Alpine packages](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=*font*&branch=edge)?

Comment: I have updated my question providing the latest findings of my research.

Comment: You don't need the version number. `apk --no-cache add msttcorefonts-installer` works.

Comment: Your question saved my day... I was skeptic before installing AL.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As you found yourself the package is called [msttcorefonts-installer](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/ppc64le/msttcorefonts-installer) in Alpine.

After installing that you get a warning:

> - With root permissions run "update-ms-fonts" and once completed
> - run "fc-cache -f" in order to update the font cache

Here is a working Dockerfile example:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add msttcorefonts-installer fontconfig && \
    update-ms-fonts && \
    fc-cache -f
```

The fontconfig package is required for fc-cache to be installed. I'm not sure if it's strictly necessary.

Comment: Upvoting, helped me to resolve issues with missing fonts when running a Java diagramming tool.